# require package only if available

Tags: emacs, path

In my `.emacs`, I have the following lines:

```
(require 'xclip)
(xclip-mode 1)
```

However, on some computers, I can't have it (e.g. on computer cluster without X11 which xclip requires).

Yet, how can I keep the same `.emacs`, for instance by using an `if` statement checking if xclip is in the PATH? I searched for tips online, but coudln't find anything. (Sorry if my question is redundant!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(when (and (executable-find "xclip")
           (require 'xclip nil 'noerror))
   (xclip-mode 1))
```

N.B. Emacs has its own path in `exec-path`, but it should be initialized to something similar to the PATH env var.